# What determines which 404 errors gets listed on a website's Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, 404, soft-404

If I put `https://example.com/french-fries` in a browser, I get a 404. Will that 404 get listed on `example.com`'s Google Search Console?

Or does `/french-fries` have to be a coded link, get crawled and get clicked on in order for that 404 to be listed in Search Console?

Our site not receiving any 404s in Google Search Console and I'm trying to make sure that everything is set up properly.

Comment: Does this page https://example.com/french-fries exists on your site? If yes, then does it crawlable and indexed? If yes, and then in future if this page will not exists on your site then only you will get a 404 listed in Google Search Console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO, I think Google doesn't care about 404 errors except for those coming from links it crawls either on your website, your sitemap or backlinks somewhere.

To capture every 404, it would have to act like a proxy between the client and your website. I suppose the analytics.js file could relay all of the other errors, but I don't see any value in it for them.

Have you checked your server logs for 404 errors?  Your server logs should show you your 404 errors and you can determine if they are links or simply users mistyping the urls.